# How to apply an ORDER and LIMIT to each sub-query in an IN() clause?

Tags: mysql

Need to select rows using multiple WHERE params but only return the latest row for each condition; prefer to hit DB with one SQL statement rather than use a loop.

**Table**

Dummy data:

```
id  first   last    
------------------------
1   jeff    jones
2   homer   simpson
3   john    doe
4   jeff    jones
5   jeff    jones
6   sam     smith
7   homer   simpson
8   john    doe
```

**SQL**

My current sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM members
WHERE (first,last) IN (('jeff','jones'), ('homer','simpson')) 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

**Results needed**

Return one row from each sub-query showing the latest entries, i.e. highest id:

```
id  first   last    
------------------------
5   jeff    jones
7   homer   simpson
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By grouping with `first, last` you get one result per combination:

```
SELECT MAX(id), first, last
  FROM members
 WHERE (first,last) IN (('jeff','jones'), ('homer','simpson')) 
 GROUP BY first, last
 ORDER BY id;
```

`MAX(id)` selects the maximum `id` per `first`/`last` combination. Order by `id` afterwards.

Check this [Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a25b2/16).

***p.s.***: added as per comment. Note: you cannot use `LIMIT` in a sub query. So use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT sup.id, sup.age, sup.first, sup.last 
  FROM members sup
  JOIN ((SELECT id, age, first, last -- choose first two Homers
           FROM members
          WHERE (first,last) IN (('homer','simpson'))
          ORDER BY id DESC 
          LIMIT 2)
          UNION 
        (SELECT id, age, first, last -- unify with first two Jeffs
           FROM members
          WHERE (first,last) IN (('jeff','jones')) 
          ORDER BY id DESC 
          LIMIT 2)) sub              -- left join 
 WHERE sup.id    = sub.id            -- and select only entries from sub
   AND sup.age   = sub.age
   AND sup.first = sub.first
   AND sup.last  = sub.last;
```

Check this [Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/817a6/45).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was going to mark your answer but wanted to do some testing first. I've added an age column, but your query only returns the first age entries and not the relevant row ages. I want it to return ages 34 and 36 which match the id, see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/817a6/1/0

Comment: In that case _PM 77-1_'s answer is basically the better option. In fact I would implement it in a similar way (see this Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/817a6/9)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but I'm not sure if this warrants a new question? I've decided I need to return the latest two rows for each sub-query; I tried to put LIMIT 2 at the end but it falls over. Is this possible with either your solution or PM 77-1's?

Comment: You could put the subquery in a derived table and join it with `members`, see update above ....

Comment: _p.s._: add `ORDER BY` at the end as you need :)

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. I've decided to stick with the original MAX solution and then if I need further rows, I'll make another DB query. Am I correct in assuming there's overhead with nested sub-queries, so it's a decision whether to use separate SQL's or use one large query. I've marked your answer as the comments were introducing scope-creep to the OP. Thanks again.

Comment: Depending on the application context in which the queries are executed, many sub queries can produce an significant overhead. Not only in terms of database access, but network traffic and round trips as well. However, if you have an index on `first`, `last` and `id` the second statement above will still perform quite well - even will millions of records (example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6eeae/1; see execution plan)

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY

```
SELECT MAX(id), first, last
FROM members
WHERE (first,last) IN (('jeff','jones'), ('homer','simpson')) 
GROUP BY first, last
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM members m1
WHERE (first,last) IN (('jeff','jones'), ('homer','simpson')) AND 
      id = (SELECT MAX(id) 
            FROM members m2
            WHERE m1.first = m2.first AND m1.last = m2.last)
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5eb12/1)